# How to create C# async powershell method?

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous, async-await

So I want to create a way to run a powershell script asynchronously. The below code is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be async because it locks up the application and the output is incorrect.

```
    public static string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(scriptText);

        // Create an IAsyncResult object and call the
        // BeginInvoke method to start running the 
        // pipeline asynchronously.
        IAsyncResult async = ps.BeginInvoke();

        // Using the PowerShell.EndInvoke method, get the
        // results from the IAsyncResult object.
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke(async))
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(result.Methods.ToString());
        } // End foreach.

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling it asynchronously.

However, you are then defeating the purpose by synchronously waiting for the asynchronous operation to finish, by calling `EndInvoke()`.

To actually run it asynchronously, you need to make your method asynchronous too.
You can do that by calling `Task.Factory.FromAsync(...)` to get a `Task<PSObject>` for the asynchronous operation, then using `await`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, my understanding of making the method async dont I just make the method start like...     public async static Task<string> RunScriptAsync(string scriptText)

Comment: @user1843359: Yes, and use the `await` keyword to wait for asynchronous operations to finish.

Comment: I had results with: `await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_ps.BeginInvoke(), pResult => _ps.EndInvoke(pResult));`

Answer (score 0):

This may not have been available when this post was made, but considering it is a top google search result it may be helpful to know that there is now an InvokeAsync command.

```
PSDataCollection<PSObject> connectionResult = await ps1.InvokeAsync();
```