# Async/Await vs TPL vs WCF Service vs Web API: So many choices

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

My ASP.Net 4 web app calls some code that spawns a Process for a long running script. The standard output is read and the returned value is updated in the database.  I would like to "fire and forget" this bit of code so that my UI remains responsive and the user doesn't have to wait around for these two operations to complete.  The end result of these two operations are not needed by the calling code so I don't think I need to "await" anything and I don't need any indication of success or failure.

I'm getting confused by all of the available options.  What is the best way to code this so that these two operations are just sent off on their merry way and do their thing on their own?

Comment: Keep in mind the danger of long-running tasks in IIS host:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "best way" may be debatable, but I would proceed with `TPL` using something like the following:

```
Task parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(someParameter));
```

Note: If the “long running script” calls a WCF service, then the following article on WCF asynchronous programming may be helpful.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/09/scale-wcf-application-better-with-asynchronous-programming.aspx

Comment: I just figured there'd be one design approach that is better than the others based on my requirements.  If I replace the term "operations" with "tasks" in my description, I feel like TPL is the way to go.

Comment: The two operations I wrapped in a single Task are to fire a PowerShell script to create a ticket in SCSM and then update the database with the returned ticket ID.  In my test environment, this could take anywhere from 15 seconds to 2 minutes or so. So far it works even if I "fire" the task and close the browser immediately.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the following articles may be useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640575/how-to-create-c-sharp-async-powershell-method and   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2010/01/21/perform-asynchronous-asset-management-using-windows-powershell-cmdlets-for-wmi.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links @Seymour.  But I don't even need to await the results of the operations.  I just need to fire them off asynchronously.  So far TPL from the server-side is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to "fire and forget" this bit of code

"Fire and forget" is almost always the wrong solution on ASP.NET.

> so that my UI remains responsive

You can make your UI responsive without changing your server side. Just execute the request asynchronously (`HttpClient` for a .NET UI; AJAX for an HTML UI).

> I don't need any indication of success or failure.

Ever? This is where we usually find out that "fire and forget" actually *isn't* what people want. A true "fire and forget" means that if the background operation never completes or has an error, then you're perfectly fine with nothing showing up in the logs.

As I said above, the best option is to handle the "asynchronous" requirement on the client side. But if you really need to do it on your server, then you have these three options:

1. Add a persistent queue with an independent backend (e.g., Azure queue with an Azure WebJob). Your web app just adds the work to the queue and returns. The independent backend reads from the queue and does the actual processing.
2. Use something like [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/). This is essentially the same, except the "queue" is a database and the backend runs alongside your ASP.NET app instead of being fully independent.
3. Use something like `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` (.NET 4.5.2) or my [AspNetBackgroundTasks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) (.NET 4.5). This is a much more dangerous option, since there is no reliable storage for the work.

Comment: I've got a good working solution implementing a single Task to handle the operations but I am concerned that perhaps I should be calling my Web API interface for this instead.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got some terms mixed.

**WCF** and **Web API** are two service platforms that allow you to make your operations available remotely through **services**.

With either technology, those exposed operations can be implemented synchronously or asynchronously but even if you chose to implement them asynchronously, the call to such operations will likely have a significant latency and thus should be invoked asynchronously.

In order to perform the **invocation of those service operations** from your ASP.NET web, you can use **libraries such as TPL** which offers you asynchronous `Tasks`. `async` and `await` are just C# keywords to ease the handling of such Tasks.

Instead of TPL, you could use other libraries and implementations such as threads to perform the invocation without blocking your web, but Tasks are the preferred way nowadays in .NET.

If you are unlikely to reuse from different applications and your long-running process or doesn't need to be located on a different machine, you may as well just implement it directly as a Task, instead of going through all the hassle of implementing a service.

Comment: I guess I was thinking either keep the code in my current project but fire it asynchronously or move it to a service and just call it remotely (asynchronously or not).  So, you are correct, it seemed like I was trying to compare different concepts.

Comment: “without blocking your web” What does that even mean?

Comment: @svick the context of the OP's question is "ASP.Net 4 web app" so that's what I was referring to as "your web": if the long running process keeps the thread in charge of delivering the response from doing so, it will "block the web"