# Powershell C# asynchronous execution

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous

I want to execute a Powershell script asynchronously in C#. I've used `BeginInvoke` method but I can't get the output/errors even though I've attached delegates for them. Here is my C# code:

```
using(ps=PowerShell.Create())
{
    PSDataCollection<PSObject> output=new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    output.DataAdded+=output_DataAdded;
    ps.AddScript(RenewalScript);
    SecureString ss = new SecureString();
    for (int i = 0; i < Password.Length; i++)
        ss.AppendChar(Password.ElementAt(i));

    PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(Username, ss);
    ps.AddParameter("Credential", cred);
    ps.AddParameter("BuildServer", Server);
    ps.AddParameter("CAServer", CAServer);
    ps.AddParameter("CAName", CAName);
    ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
    var result=ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);

}

void output_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    //display output in UI
}

void Error_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    //display error message in UI
}
```

I have multiple `Write-Output` statements in my script. However, the `DataAdded` methods are never triggered. But they are triggered when I use the synchronous `Invoke` method.

Comment: You've got a using statement with an asynchronous `BeginInvoke`. The host `PowerShell` object is going to get disposed before the command pipeline completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640575/how-to-create-c-sharp-async-powershell-method).
To actually run it asynchronously, you need to make your method asynchronous too.
You can do that by calling `Task.Factory.FromAsync(...)` to get a `Task<PSObject>` for the asynchronous operation, then using `await`.