# Run power shell command to pickup GPU usage by process on c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to pickup GPU usage of my c# app but there is no way i can doit and make that wrk with NVDIA, AMD, or Intel.
Trough powershell is possible to obtain that info, example:

```
   $p = Get-Process MyAPP; ((Get-Counter "\GPU Engine(pid_$($p.id)*engtype_3D)\Utilization Percentage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue |foreach {Write-Output "$([math]::Round($_,1))%"}
```

This show the gpu usage and work like a charm on any graphic card.
How can pickup in asyncronous way the result?
Of curse async in order not create blocking thread.

```
  PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
  ps.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"e:\gpu.ps"));  //the script.
  var gpu = ps.BeginInvoke();
  gpuinfobox.Text = gpu.ToString();  //of curse this not work!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640622/2864740 — then it can be used as async/await. More details for converting APM (Beginxx, Endxx) to TAP (async/await) be found in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke as well “Invoke the Command asynchronously. *Use EndInvoke() to obtain the output of the command.*”

Comment: You are reading a performance counter. Just do it directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Comment: Thanks so much  user2864740, is working now!

Comment: @user2864740 Please post as answer so the OP can accept. Otherwise this question wil remain 'unanswered' and very few people having the same problem would be able to find it.

Comment: He already put the answer, anyway I update this now with full code, user2864740
  provide a very good guide with that answer and guide me to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here the full code to pickup the GPU usage from your app or any process, put inside a timer fire this every one second. Work with Intel, Nvidia, AMD.

```
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0,1000);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();


async  private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"e:\gpu.ps"));
    var task = Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>>.Factory.FromAsync(ps.BeginInvoke(), ps.EndInvoke);
    var objs = await task;
    if (objs.Count > 0)
    {
        var result = objs[0].ToString();
        TextBox.Text  =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null : result;
    }
 }
```

The script gpu.ps:

```
$p = Get-Process YourApp; ((Get-Counter "\GPU Engine(pid_$($p.id)*engtype_3D)\Utilization Percentage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue |foreach {Write-Output "$([math]::Round($_,1))%"}
```

Script for global gpu , cpu etc, take a lok on:
https://superuser.com/questions/1632758/how-to-get-gpu-usage-and-gpu-memory-info-of-a-process-by-powershell7